# Filter an array with PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [DEB_Date] => 2018-01-06
            [DEB_Total] => 100.00
            [DEB_Nb_Days] => 181
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [DEB_Date] => 2018-07-06
            [DEB_Total] => 100.00
            [DEB_Nb_Days] => 0
        )
)
```

I want to have a sort of report depending the `DEB_Nb_Days`.

So my script is the following:

```
// Init the array
$arr['0_to_30']['DEB_Total'] = 0;
$arr['31_to_60']['DEB_Total'] = 0;
$arr['61_to_90']['DEB_Total'] = 0;
$arr['91_to_120']['DEB_Total'] = 0;
$arr['121_and_more']['DEB_Total'] = 0;

// Loop between the debtors
foreach($debtors as $debtor){
    if($debtor['DEB_Nb_Days'] >= 0  || $debtor['DEB_Nb_Days'] <= 30) { $arr['0_to_30']['DEB_Total'] += $debtor['DEB_Total']; }
    if($debtor['DEB_Nb_Days'] >= 31 || $debtor['PAY_Nb_Days'] <= 60) { $arr['31_to_60']['DEB_Total'] += $debtor['DEB_Total']; }
    if($debtor['DEB_Nb_Days'] >= 61 || $debtor['PAY_Nb_Days'] <= 90) { $arr['61_to_90']['DEB_Total'] += $debtor['DEB_Total']; }
    if($debtor['DEB_Nb_Days'] >= 91 || $debtor['PAY_Nb_Days'] <= 120) { $arr['91_to_120']['DEB_Total'] += $debtor['DEB_Total']; }
    if($debtor['PAY_Nb_Days'] >= 121) { $arr['121_and_more']['DEB_Total'] += $debtor['DEB_Total']; }
}
```

I should have this:

```
$arr['0_to_30']['DEB_Total'] = 100;
$arr['31_to_60']['DEB_Total'] = 0;
$arr['61_to_90']['DEB_Total'] = 0;
$arr['91_to_120']['DEB_Total'] = 0;
$arr['121_and_more']['DEB_Total'] = 100;
```

But actually the result is:

```
$arr['0_to_30']['DEB_Total'] = 200;
$arr['31_to_60']['DEB_Total'] = 200;
$arr['61_to_90']['DEB_Total'] = 200;
$arr['91_to_120']['DEB_Total'] = 200;
$arr['121_and_more']['DEB_Total'] = 0;
```

What I'm missed here please ?

Thanks.

Comment: Probably change || to &&

Comment: `$debtor['DEB_Nb_Days'] >= 31 || $debtor['PAY_Nb_Days'] <= 60`  You should be using && and what is PAY_Nb_Days?  Enable error reporting so you get notices about undefined indexes.

Comment: All of your "OR" conditions (`||`) need to be "AND" conditions (`&&`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could restructure the set of if conditions to look for the highest first and then use `else` to reduce the number of comparisons...

```
foreach ($debtors as $debtor) {
    if ($debtor['DEB_Nb_Days'] >= 121) {
        $arr['121_and_more']['DEB_Total'] += $debtor['DEB_Total'];
    } 
    else if ($debtor['DEB_Nb_Days'] >= 91) {
        $arr['91_to_120']['DEB_Total'] += $debtor['DEB_Total'];
    } 
    else if ($debtor['DEB_Nb_Days'] >= 61) {
        $arr['61_to_90']['DEB_Total'] += $debtor['DEB_Total'];
    } 
    else if ($debtor['DEB_Nb_Days'] >= 31) {
        $arr['31_to_60']['DEB_Total'] += $debtor['DEB_Total'];
    } 
    else {
        $arr['0_to_30']['DEB_Total'] += $debtor['DEB_Total'];
    }
}
```

( This also corrects that at some points your using `PAY_Nb_Days` instead of `DEB_Nb_Days` ).